# How to configure filebeat kubernetes deamon to index on namespace or pod name

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, elastic-stack, filebeat

I am currently attempting to get the logs from my kubernetes cluster to an external ElasticSearch/Kibana. So far I have used [this](https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/master/deploy/kubernetes/filebeat-kubernetes.yaml) daemon deployment to get filebeat running and piping to my external server, but I am unable to figure out how to set the index to something meaningfull. [This](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/elasticsearch-output.html) documentation page tells me that I need to create am index key in the output.elasticsearch section, but I don't know what to put in the value.

My desired output format would be something along the lines of `<cluster-name>-<namespace>-<pod name>`

IE: `devKube-frontend-publicAPI-123abc`

Answer (score 1):

Precondition: You have enabled [`add_kubernetes_metadata: ~`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/add-kubernetes-metadata.html).

Then you can use that metadata in the index name like this:

```
output.elasticsearch:
  index: "%{[kubernetes.namespace]:filebeat}-%{[beat.version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
```

- `%{[kubernetes.namespace]:filebeat}`: Use the Kubernetes namespace or if there is none fall back to `filebeat`.
- Adding `%{[beat.version]}` is highly recommended for the scenario when you upgrade Filebeat and there is a breaking change in the mapping. This should be limited to major version changes (if at all), but is an issue you can easily avoid with this setting.
- A time based index pattern like `%{+yyyy.MM.dd}` or even better would be an [ILM policy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/ilm.html) to have evenly and properly sized shards.

PS: You have the Pod name and other details in fields from `add_kubernetes_metadata: ~`. I would be careful not to cut the indices into tiny pieces, since every shard has a certain amount of overhead. The default Filebeat ILM policy is 50GB per shard — if your shards are smaller than 10GB you will most likely run into issues at some point. Leave the indices a bit more coarse grained and just use a filter for a specific Pod instead.

Comment: Hey, i tried to follow this but does not work. Can u tell me what must add_kubernetes_metadata looks like ?

Comment: `add_kubernetes_metadata: ~` is all that should be needed if the beat can use the Kubernetes API, but the linked documentation has more details. If you have errors when the Beat starts up related to that metadata, you should open a new thread.